# Get Name of item from SetupEntityAccess SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I'm working on a query that would involving the SetupEntityAccess object in salesforce. I noticed that there is no field that shows what the name of the item is, but only the type of the item such as Apex Class and SetupEntityId. Is it possible to do a query that would return the name of each item as to what the SetupEntityId relates to?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can query each Setup Entry which `SetupEntryAccess` you need one by one and in the following manner

```
SELECT Id, Name, (
    SELECT Id
        , Parent.Name
        , Parent.Profile.Name
    FROM SetupEntityAccessItems
)
FROM ApexClass
LIMIT 10
```

it will give you the following result which you could iterate over in Apex.

[image]

The same you can do for other types:

- ApexClass for Apex classes
- ApexPage for Visualforce pages
- In API version 28.0 and later, ConnectedApplication for OAuth connected apps
- In API version 31.0 and later, CustomPermission for custom permissions
- In API version 28.0 and later, ServiceProvider for service providers
- In API version 28.0 and later, TabSet for apps
- In API version 48.0 and later, CustomEntityDefinition for Custom Settings and Custom Metadata Types